# Add Header to an XML to CSV conversion using XQuery

Tags: xquery

Hi I am trying to convert some xml to csv using xquery and found a previous post that helped me get to this point:

```
for $b in /root/Result
return 
  concat(escape-html-uri(string-join(($b/HolidayEndDate,
                                      $b/HolidayType,
                                      $b/FirstName,                                                 
                                      $b/AllowanceRemainingDays,
                                      $b/HolidayStartDate,
                                      $b/EmployeeId,
                                      $b/AllowanceDays,
                                      $b/LastName,
                                      $b/HolidayDurationDays
                                      )
                                       /normalize-space(),
                                    ",")
                         ),
         codepoints-to-string(10))
```

This returns all of the data as required but no Header row. Is there a simple addition to the above code that would also return the header row? Thanks. :)

Comment: Not a direct answer to your question, but you might find my gist useful for reference, since it produces a header row: https://gist.github.com/joewiz/48ce061423aa7d3ada28. More recently, I began uses XQuery 3.1 when generating CSV/TSV: https://gist.github.com/joewiz/86dca7f97db4694853b20f8cba427539.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
concat("HolidayEndDate,HolidayType,FirstName,AllowanceRemainingDays,HolidayStartDate,EmployeeId,AllowanceDays,LastName,HolidayDurationDays&#10;",
    string-join(
        for $b in /root/Result
        return 
          concat(escape-html-uri(string-join(($b/HolidayEndDate,
                                          $b/HolidayType,
                                          $b/FirstName,                                                 
                                          $b/AllowanceRemainingDays,
                                          $b/HolidayStartDate,
                                          $b/EmployeeId,
                                          $b/AllowanceDays,
                                          $b/LastName,
                                          $b/HolidayDurationDays
                                          )
                                           /normalize-space(),
                                        ",")
                             ),
                 codepoints-to-string(10)), "")
)
```

Comment: Thank you very much! This is exactly what i was needing!

Answer (score 1):

Since your query returns a sequence of lines, you can just prepend another line *before* the FLWOR expression:

```
"HolidayEndDate,HolidayType,FirstName,AllowanceRemainingDays,HolidayStartDate,EmployeeId,AllowanceDays,LastName,HolidayDurationDays&#10;",

for $b in /root/Result
return 
  concat(escape-html-uri(string-join(($b/HolidayEndDate,
                                      $b/HolidayType,
                                      $b/FirstName,                                                 
                                      $b/AllowanceRemainingDays,
                                      $b/HolidayStartDate,
                                      $b/EmployeeId,
                                      $b/AllowanceDays,
                                      $b/LastName,
                                      $b/HolidayDurationDays
                                      )
                                       /normalize-space(),
                                    ",")
                         ),
         codepoints-to-string(10))
```

Because nested sequences are *flattened* (i.e. concatenated) in XQuery, this results in one output sequence including the header. Note also that I used a character entity `'&#10;'` for the newline character, which is much shorter than `codepoints-to-string(10)`.

Comment: Sequence items are serialized with a space separator so there is an extra space at the beginning of the second line.
Adding a call to concat() sounds enough to fix this.

Comment: Hi Leo, Thank you very much for solution this works and gives the desired output. However like Alain has mentioned all of my data under the header has a leading space. Is there a possible fix for this? Thanks very much!

Comment: @Alain Couthures Could you provide a code example of how you would fix the leading space on each row issue please? Thanks